# Настройка роутинга в Yii2 при проксировании

Tags: yii2, iis

Создан локальный сервер на IIS, установлен yii2-basic, корневой директорией указана папка /web, прописан подсмотренный конфиг:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
        <rule name="Hide Yii Index" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

и размещен в папке/web.

yii работает, все отлично.

На внешнем сервере настроено проксирование вида: http://server2/yii -> http://localserver/

Настроен baseUrl на оба сервера:

```
'baseUrl' => preg_match("/172(.*)/", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? '' : '/yii'
```

Оба сайта работают, стили применились, но на server2 ссылки выглядят так:
http://server2/index.php?r=site%2Fabout

В пути отсутствует /yii. Если руками в ссылке дописать /yii, то попадаю, куда надо.

Если активировать urlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

тогда ссылки выглядят так: 
http://server2/yii/site/about

Выглядит как надо, однако, все ссылки ведут на главную страницу
Локальный сайт при этом корректно работает.

Где что упустил? Где прокосячил?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась путем изменения регулярки в web.config на локальном сервере

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
  <rule name="Hide Yii Index" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)\?*$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Не забываем также, что при проксировании в proxy_pass **не ставить** закрывающий слеш после адреса.